# R Shiny: Switch between table and plot in renderUI

Tags: r, shiny, uioutput

I am trying to let the user select the kind of display he wishes, but when I try to render the plot it gives me an error.

Here is the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(data.table)

runApp(list(
    ui = fluidPage(
        wellPanel(
            radioButtons("visuBtn", NULL, choices = c(Table = "table", Plot = "plot"))
        ),
        wellPanel(
            uiOutput("DataTable")
        )
    ),
    server = function(input, output){

        observeEvent(input$visuBtn,{
            output$DataTable <- renderUI({
                dfconc <- data.table(time = c(1,2,3,4,5), concentration = c(0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.7, 0.8))

                if(input$visuBtn == "table"){
                    output$aa <- renderDataTable(dfconc, options = list(paging = FALSE, searching = FALSE))
                    dataTableOutput("aa")
                }
                else { ### NOT WORKING
                    output$aa <- renderPlot({
                        plot(dfconc$time, dfconc$concentration, xlab = "Time", ylab = "Concentration")
                    })
                    fixedRow(
                        plotOutput("aa")
                    )
                }      ###

            })
        })
    }
))
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: check [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/2136) for this error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think its better if you render the outputs on the client side and then simply `show` and `hide` the elements based on the selection. This way you're not wasting resources on the `server` side

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(DT)
library(data.table)

runApp(list(
  ui = fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    wellPanel(
      radioButtons("visuBtn", NULL, choices = c(Table = "table", Plot = "plot"))
    ),
    wellPanel(
      dataTableOutput("mytable"),
      plotOutput("myplot")
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session){

    dfconc <- data.table(time = c(1,2,3,4,5), concentration = c(0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.7, 0.8))

    output$mytable <- renderDataTable(
      dfconc, options = list(paging = FALSE, searching = FALSE)
    )

    output$myplot <- renderPlot({
      plot(dfconc$time, dfconc$concentration, xlab = "Time", ylab = "Concentration")
    })

    observeEvent(input$visuBtn,{
      req(input$visuBtn)
      if(input$visuBtn == "plot"){
        hide("mytable")
        show("myplot")
      }else{
        hide("myplot")
        show("mytable")
      }
    })
  }
))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm gonna use this. But I wonder why my version would not work.

Comment: You had the outputs with same id `output$aa`, you can only have 1 unique id per output

Comment: dear @PorkChop could you please help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59129562/in-r-shiny-how-to-fix-error-in-sourcing-app-as-nothing-changes-when-clicking-on?fbclid=IwAR2XoSXF7weHkpZ2a9rOXa69KgKcgeMGO6xdQ2Xv1ZRUKWmAa7bVeZlktMo

Answer (score 2):

Agree with @Pork Chop. But why not simply use a `conditionalPanel`

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(data.table)

runApp(list(
  ui = fluidPage(
    wellPanel(
      radioButtons("visuBtn", NULL, choices = c(Table = "table", Plot = "plot"))
    ),

      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.visuBtn == 'table'",
        DTOutput('aa')
      ),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.visuBtn == 'plot'",
        plotOutput('bb')
      )

  ),
  server = function(input, output){
    dfconc <- data.table(time = c(1,2,3,4,5), concentration = c(0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.7, 0.8))

          output$aa <- renderDT(dfconc, options = list(paging = FALSE, searching = FALSE))
          output$bb <- renderPlot({
            plot(dfconc$time, dfconc$concentration, xlab = "Time", ylab = "Concentration")
          })
        } 

))
```